# Qual a diferença entre primary key e index no mysql?

Tags: mysql

Queria saber se há alguma diferença entre primary key e index.
Pq no mysql tem varios tipos de indexs (PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, INDEX, and FULLTEXT).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um índice é simplesmente um auxiliar na hora de fazer uma busca (por exemplo, um SELECT) em cima de uma coluna. Por exemplo, numa tabela com nomes de pessoas, adicionar um índice para o NOME ajuda a acelerar buscas por nome, e também seleções que obtenham linhas por ordem alfabética de nome.

Buscar num campo sem índice demora um tempo linearmente proporcional ao número de linhas. Buscar num campo sem índice demora um tempo proporcional ao logaritmo do número de linhas. Quando há 100 milhões de linhas, isso faz bastante diferença, porque log(100 milhões) = 8.

Um índice UNIQUE indica que só pode haver um exemplar da coluna para cada linha. Isso é apropriado para colunas que são sabidamente únicas (tipo CPF de pessoas) mas não seria nada apropriado para nomes, porque homônimos são muito comuns.

PRIMARY KEY, ou chave primária, é um conceito diferente de índice, embora geralmente a primary key seja indexada para acelerar a busca. Uma chave primária é uma coluna que só pode haver um exemplar para cada linha *E* essa coluna serve para identificar essa linha. O CPF poderia ser uma chave primária para uma tabela de pessoas físicas, mas o mais recomendado é usar uma chave primária abstrata - um código sequencial crescente ou um hash, para facilitar alterações posteriores (se a sua tabela de pessoas físicas precisar incluir estrangeiros no futuro, o CPF deixa de ser uma boa chave primária e nem pode mais ser indexado UNIQUE).

O FULLTEXT eu não conheço mas presumo que seja um índice para facilitar buscas que envolvam partes de uma coluna textual (tipo, buscar por fragmento do nome em vez de nome completo)